# Link on h1 heading doubles size of imported web font

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website in Visual Studio and am having a problem with CSS/HTML and an imported web font.

I've set up a style for the h1 tags within an area on screen that is class .mid, and also included a style for `<a>` tag children of the h1 tag in the same code block. I want some h1 headings to act as links and change colour when hovered over and others to just be static. I then set up another definition that simply sets the colour to change on the hover state whilst leaving the other attributes unchanged.

While the colour change works and the h1 link is styled like plain h1 headings the text is much larger (see pic)

[image: How the text renders]

The CSS code:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,500,700,900);

.mid h1, .mid h2, .mid h3, .mid h1 a:link, .mid h1 a:active, .mid h1 a:hover, .mid h1 a:visited {
        font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;   
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: left;
        color: rgb(180,180,180);
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.mid h1, .mid h1 a, .mid h1 a:link, .mid h1 a:active, .mid h1 a:hover, .mid h1 a:visited {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        line-height: 2.1em;
    }

.mid h1 a:hover   {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        line-height: 2.1em;
        color: rgb(180,255,0);
    }
```

I've tried setting the size again in the hover definition but it doesn't make any difference. When I remove the `<a>` link from the heading the size returns to normal. Strangely there is nothing larger than the h1 font-size attribute in the whole CSS document and assume that the size attribute is for some reason being applied twice to the heading or that there is some sort of conflict leading to this odd behaviour.

Another oddity is that setting the font size to 1.0em solves the problem (but renders the h1 too small).

The HTML is as follows:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>

<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>

<div class ="rule"></div>

<h1><a href = "http://www.mylink.com">Graphic Design</a></h1>
<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.</p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your browser's dom inspector should be able to show you where each rule that affects your element comes from.

Comment: Thank you, very useful advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`em` units act a bit like percentages -- nesting a `1.4em` inside a `1.4em` (as you're doing on `h1` and `h1 a`) results in `1.96em` compared to the document.

You could omit the extra `em` statements, and only keep it on the `h1` -- or use `rem` units instead; those will set sizes relative to the document root rather than relative to the current element:

```css
.em  { font-size: 1.4em }
.rem { font-size: 1.4rem }
```

```html
<div class="em">1.4em
  <div class="em">1.4em
    <div class="em">1.4em</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rem">1.4rem
  <div class="rem">1.4rem
    <div class="rem">1.4rem</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="unstyled">foo</div>
```

Psuedoclasses are slightly different -- they act as replacements for the base class rules, not as children of the base class.  Which is to say, if you have the following rules:

```
a       {font-size: 1.4em}
a:hover {font-size: 1.4em}
```

Hover will keep the item at 1.4em, *not* 1.96em, because the `:hover` rule replaces the same rule on the base class instead of multiplying it.

Comment: Many thanks, that will be the answer: the pseudo class is multiplying the size value to the h1 value so that the total enlargement is 1.4 * 1.4 = 1.96. This also explains why setting the size to 1.0 em has no effect 1.0 * 1.0 = 1.0.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Strictly speaking it wasn't the `:hover` pseudoclass causing you problems; you were setting 1.4em on both `h1` and `h1 a` itself, that's where the multiplication came in.  Updated the answer with details on that (I had to test it out to prove it to myself, I don't think I'd ever consciously realized that that was how pseudoclasses worked....)